# CoffeeScript String Interpolation with For In Loop Adds Commas

Tags: arrays, string, loops, coffeescript, interpolation

This coffeescript...

```
"""
#{@display_event_small(event) for event in data.top_events}
"""
```

outputs commas between each of the elements in data.top_events. I need to have them concatenate without commas in between. Of course, I could use a more customized loop, but I would imagine CoffeeScript has a nicer way of changing this behavior.

Let me know if I need to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop expression results in an array so you could explicitly join the elements with an empty string delimiter:

```
"""
#{(@display_event_small(event) for event in data.top_events).join('')}
"""
```

There's no special formatting options for `"#{}"`, CoffeeScript just turns it inside out and hands it off to JavaScript's `+`. An interpolated string like `"a #{b} c"` becomes

```
"a " + b + " c"
```

when compiled to JavaScript and JavaScript is inserting the commas when it stringifies your array.

Comment: It's the contrast between `[1,2,3].toString()` and `[1,2,3].join('')`.